# ApplicationStartHandlerRunnable: Code factory class OBJECT could NOT be loaded

Tags: java

I have downloaded **fmagic** release 0.1.0 in order to check the document archive functions of the framework. There is a template application **MediaApp** provided by the framework. I built it successfully (with Maven, like recommended) and started it as a cloud commander service successfully, using the following command line:

```
mediaapp manager service localhost:8001 wait RootPath=c:/fmagic/run
                                                   AccessKey=abc ShutdownKey=123
```

But after starting the remote application with the following command line

```
mediaapp application start localhost:8001:abc wait CodeName=server Port=8020
```

I got an error message as a response:

```
# fmagic application start localhost:8001:abc wait CodeName=server6 Port=8031
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.ReturnValue=Error
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.Error=Notification.Fcc.Server.Error.FccCommand.ErrorOnProcessingFccCommand

#
# Error message reported by the FCC server:
#
#
# --> ApplicationStartHandlerRunnable: Code factory class OBJECT could NOT be loaded.
# --> Application identifier searched for: 'MediaApp'
# --> Class package path searched for: 'mediaapp.deploy'
# --> Please pay attention to the build process:
#     1. The class 'GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode' must be created/generated first.
#     2. This class has to be compiled into the build in a second step.
#     3. That means: You should execute the build process twice.
#
```

The fmagic service is still running without grumbling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if the code factory class "GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode" is not integrated in the current build.

Please notice:

After you have copied the template classes into your IDE into the package "mediaapp.deploy" (recommended) you should see th­e following classes in your IDE. You will find 6 Java files.

```
MediaAppClientApplication.java
MediaAppFccClient.java
MediaAppGenerateApplicationCodeHandler.java
MediaAppMain.java
MediaAppServerApplication.java
MediaAppUtilMedia.java
```

After building your **fmagic** application, you will find 7 Java files. You should see the factory class "GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode.java" additionally. This class is to be generated during the build process. Please refresh your IDE to synchronize the view.

```
GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode.java
```

If this class "GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode" was **not** created, the build process failed or is incomplete.

A complete build process of a **fmagic** application includes 3 main steps at least: (1) Compile, (2) Build and run executable "MediaAppGenerateApplicationCodeHandler.java" which is supposed to create the code factory class, (3) Compile again, in order to integrate the most recent version of the code factory class "GeneratedMediaAppApplicationCode.java" into the final build.

Please let the build mechanism run twice, the first time for creating the code factory class, the second time to integrate the most recent version of the created class into the final build.

Once your application has been built successfully, you can test the cloud commander function again. Let's have look at an example.

First, start "mediaapp" as a **fmagic** cloud commander within a command line tool as a service:

```
mediaapp manager service localhost:8001 wait RootPath=c:/fmagic/run
                                                AccessKey=abc ShutdownKey=123
```

Then, start a **fmagic** server application instance, e. g. with the code name “server6” at port 8031 (like suggested by the document archive template), using another command line tool window:

```
mediaapp application start localhost:8001:abc wait CodeName=server6 Port=8031
```

You should see the following response:

```
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.ReturnValue=Ok
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.ProcessingTime=07/12/2013 16:15:10
```

You may request a runtime check ...

```
mediaapp application info localhost:8001:abc status Port=8031 RuntimeCheck
```

and get back the status of the started application:

```
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.ReturnValue=Ok
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.Manager.ProcessingTime=07/12/2013 16:18:26
Info.Fcc.Server.Identifier.FccInfoApplication.RuntimeCheck=Ok
```